# Docusign [[Conditional]] value set for email resource file

Tags: docusignapi

is there a list of the field/value that can be used in the email resource file?  The docusign-email-resource-file(v1.1).pdf references some of the fields but does not say how many fields exists or where to find a list.  I'm trying to create a branding template that will show the other signer's names in the email based on the condition of which signer number it's sent to.

EG. if email is going to signer 1, the signer 2,3,4 names are displayed in the email.
if going to signer 2, signer 1,3,4 names are displayed.

Docusign doesn't seem to have any other documentation around the email resource file besides the pdf which is frustrating

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check/accept the best answer to each of your questions. *Thank you!*

Answer (score 0):

Changing the resource files are not supported by regular DocuSign support policies. If you want to change them then you're on your own.

Re docs: read/search the resource files themselves to see the ever-changing list of options/strings that can be updated.

Notes: be very careful with your changes. Download the default file, and save it carefully so you can go back to it if needed. Recommended: use a change control system such as git so you can track exactly what you've changed for your testing and be able to reverse your changes as needed.

### Your use case: showing signers who the other signers are

Rather than changing the branding file, I'd suggest using the API to programmatically set the email messages (the [emailBlub](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_emailblurb) field) to contain the information about the signers.

You could set the message to be the same for all the signers to include the names of all the signers. Or you can use signer-specific emailBlurb fields to tell just some of the signers who the other signers are.

Comment: The resource file is part of the branding functionality, how is that support by docusign? Which questions why make something like this and not give all the information you need to use it?

Comment: Larry K, the emailBlub field is an "optional element holds the body of the email message that is sent to all envelope recipients".  If I want to limit what signer 1 sees compared to signer 2, I don't think it would be something the emailBlub field can support.  We tired looking at adding a RecipientEmailNotification but it didn't work as well as expected

Comment: For a signer-specific email blurb, use `emailNotification` attribute. I just tried it and it worked well. If you have further questions about it, ask a new question.

Comment: We did figure out how to best use this.  We leverage RecipientEmailNotification and added emailsubject/email body.  What we discovered is that you could inject the [[Data:]] command into the fields.  I didn't see this in the documentation but it works and that's all the matters